# overlining support in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app, gnome-terminal, iterm2

when I enter `printf "\e[4m%s\e[0m\n" TESTING` into iterm or osx terminal, testing returns underlined.

Are there any terminals (mac or linux) that would support `printf "\e[53m%s\e[0m\n" TESTING`?

Comment: Where did you get the `\e[53m` sequence from? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @grawity I found it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes

Which is far from an ideal reference.